# How do I carry over an integer from within a if/else if code into an integer from outside that code? (java)

Tags: java, string, if-statement, integer, exponent

I'm trying to write a code that can solve exponential questions, and can solve exponential questions from integer inputs and word inputs (i.e one, two... etc).  I've pretty much figured out the integer parts, however i'm stuck on the "Word input" part. Mainly, the final part in my code for the word part (int base = y, exponent = z), in which i can calculate the exponent doesn't work because y and z cannot be pulled from the if/else if statements

How do i make my code so that int base = y, exponent = z can pull from their respective if/else if codes?

Thanks a bunch!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for Alphabetical Input, 2 for numerical input:");
    int solution = choice.nextInt();

    if(solution == 1) {
        for(int i=1; i<=100;i++) {
            Scanner words = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter your base");
            String x = words.toString();
            String x1 = "zero";
            String x2 = "one";
            String x3 = "two";
            String x4 = "three";
            String x5 = "four";
            String x6 = "five";
            String x7 = "six";
            String x8 = "seven";
            String x9 = "eight";
            String x10 = "nine";
            String x11 = "ten";

            if(x == x1) {
                int y = 0;
            }
            else if(x == x2) {
                int y = 1;
            }
            else if(x == x3) {
                int y = 2;
            }
            else if(x == x4) {
                int y = 3;
            }
            else if (x == x5) {
                int y = 4;
            }
            else if (x == x6) {
                int y = 5;
            }
            else if (x == x7) {
                int y = 6;
            }
            else if (x == x8) {
                int y = 7;
            }
            else if (x == x9) {
                int y = 8;
            }
            else if (x == x10) {
                int y = 9;
            }
            else if (x == x11) {
                int y = 10;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("I can't read that!");
            }
            System.out.println("Enter your exponent");

            Scanner exponent = new Scanner(System.in);

            String a = exponent.toString();


            if(a == x1) {
                int z = 0;
            }
            else if(a == x2) {
                int z = 1;
            }
            else if(a == x3) {
                int z = 2;
            }
            else if(a == x4) {
                int z = 3;
            }
            else if (a == x5) {
                int z = 4;
            }
            else if (a == x6) {
                int z = 5;
            }
            else if (a == x7) {
                int z = 6;
            }
            else if (a == x8) {
                int z = 7;
            }
            else if (a == x9) {
                int z = 8;
            }
            else if (a == x10) {
                int z = 9;
            }
            else if (a == x11) {
                int z = 10;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("I can't read that!");
            }
            int base = y, exponents = z; //this does not work, y and z aren't pulled 
            double result = Math.pow(base, exponents);
            }

    }
    else if(solution ==2 ) {
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
            Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter your base:");

            int x = number.nextInt();

            Scanner up = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter your exponent:");

            int y = up.nextInt();

            int base = x, exponent = y;
            double result = Math.pow(base, exponent);

            System.out.println("Answer = " + result);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Could not read input");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Declare them as [@Shuang Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9069929/shuang-li) said in front of the for-loop as otherwise y and z are only visible within the regarding if.

Apart from that you should not use `if (x == x1)` as this checks if your input is equal to the memory address of String x1 and thus will print out "I can't read that!". For checking if the strings are equal you want to use `if (x.equals(x1))`.

Further reading in the user's input using `String x = words.toString();` is not doing what you would want it to do as it instantly skips to the if-part passing `null` to `String x`. Instead you should use

`String x = words.next();` or `String x = words.nextLine();`

as unlike to `.toString();` the methods `.next();` and `.nextLine();` are methods of `Scanner` and so they will wait for any input and only after getting an input the code will be further executed.

So this would be the could you would aim for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for Alphabetical Input, 2 for numerical input:");
    int solution = choice.nextInt();

    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    if (solution == 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            Scanner words = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter your base");
            String x = words.next();
            String x1 = "zero";
            String x2 = "one";
            String x3 = "two";
            String x4 = "three";
            String x5 = "four";
            String x6 = "five";
            String x7 = "six";
            String x8 = "seven";
            String x9 = "eight";
            String x10 = "nine";
            String x11 = "ten";

            if (x.equals(x1)) {
                y = 0;
            } else if (x.equals(x2)) {
                y = 1;
            } else if (x.equals(x3)) {
                y = 2;
            } else if (x.equals(x4)) {
                y = 3;
            } else if (x.equals(x5)) {
                y = 4;
            } else if (x.equals(x6)) {
                y = 5;
            } else if (x.equals(x7)) {
                y = 6;
            } else if (x.equals(x8)) {
                y = 7;
            } else if (x.equals(x9)) {
                y = 8;
            } else if (x.equals(x10)) {
                y = 9;
            } else if (x.equals(x11)) {
                y = 10;
            } else {
                System.out.println("I can't read that!");
            }
            System.out.println("Enter your exponent");

            Scanner exponent = new Scanner(System.in);

            String a = exponent.next();

            if (a.equals(x1)) {
                z = 0;
            } else if (a.equals(x2)) {
                z = 1;
            } else if (a.equals(x3)) {
                z = 2;
            } else if (a.equals(x4)) {
                z = 3;
            } else if (a.equals(x5)) {
                z = 4;
            } else if (a.equals(x6)) {
                z = 5;
            } else if (a.equals(x7)) {
                z = 6;
            } else if (a.equals(x8)) {
                z = 7;
            } else if (a.equals(x9)) {
                z = 8;
            } else if (a.equals(x10)) {
                z = 9;
            } else if (a.equals(x11)) {
                z = 10;
            } else {
                System.out.println("I can't read that!");
            }
            int base = y, exponents = z; // this does not work, y and z aren't pulled
            double result = Math.pow(base, exponents);
            System.out.println("Answer = " + result);
        }

    } else if (solution == 2) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter your base:");

            int x = number.nextInt();

            Scanner up = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter your exponent:");

            y = up.nextInt();

            int base = x, exponent = y;
            double result = Math.pow(base, exponent);

            System.out.println("Answer = " + result);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not read input");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare y and z in front of the entire for loop.
What u did before in those if is that you declare a variable, you assigned a value to that variable and you throw it away immediately. This is no python. IDE should give you a warning for that.